# Set color from object on the basis of key to radio button on "map" REACT/Materialui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I am stuck with This I have two objects :

```
options = {'Not Ok':'Not Ok', 'Watch':'Watch', 'Ok':'Ok'};
choice_colors = {'Ok':'green', 'Not Ok':'red', 'Watch':'yellow'};
```

I am using a map function to generate radio buttons with reference to material UI

```
    let choices = _map(options, function(choice, key){  
 return  <FormControlLabel key={key}
 id={key}
 value={key+''}
 control={<Radio />}
 label="" 
/>;
```

I am getting desired output 3 radio buttons from `control={<Radio />}`

But now I want to set the color for each of them according to their key values like :
first radio button have key 'ok then its color should be "green" in reference from

```
choice_colors = {'Ok':'green', 'Not Ok':"red", 'Watch':'yellow'};
```

I tried

```
control={<Radio style={{color:'red'}} />}
```

above passing red to all three radios

```
control={<Radio style={{color:`${key==="Ok" ? red : ' '}`}} />}
```

above not giving desired out put cause I am not able to add multiple check

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: `red` is being evaluated to `undefined`. You should use a string: `control={<Radio style={{color: key === "Ok" ? "red" : "" }} />}`. If you want to use the choice_colors dictionary:  `control={<Radio style={{color: choice_colors[key] }} />}`

Comment: ok But can I use condition in one color style for 3 radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the choice_colors dictionary in your Radio style property like so:

```
const options = {'Not Ok':'Not Ok', 'Watch':'Watch', 'Ok':'Ok'};
const choice_colors = {'Ok':'green', 'Not Ok':'red', 'Watch':'yellow'};

let choices = _map(options, function(choice, key) {  
 return (
   <FormControlLabel key={key}
     id={key}
     value={key+''}
     control={<Radio style={{ color: choice_colors[key] }} />}
     label="" 
   />
 );
});
```